# SQL; Plus + or Minus – Instead of Dates (ASP.NET-C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, date, datediff

I am Working On ASP.NET_C# Application

I am pulling out some Dates form SQL on a Grid View.

But instead of those Dates, I like to see how mush “Plus +” or “minus –“ It is form Today’s Date.

For Example

Today’s Date is = 11/02/2012

If the Date from SQL is 07/02/2012, I like my Grid to show -4

Or

If the Date from SQL is 17/02/2012, I like my Grid to show +6

Please Help me, How do I go about doing that….

This is My SQL Query; That I am working With

```
SELECT MAX(AmountPay.DateUpto) AS [ PaidUpTo], TimeTable.Name, TimeTable.Ref, TimeTable.Time11to12 FROM AmountPay FULL OUTER JOIN TimeTable ON AmountPay.Ref = TimeTable.Ref WHERE (TimeTable.Time11to12 = @Time11to12) GROUP BY TimeTable.Name, TimeTable.Ref, TimeTable.Time11to12
```

AmountPay.DateUpto is the Date I Like see as + or -

I have Been Suggested Datediff Function; and I have Used datediff function for working out things like Age from Date of Birth but I can't work out; how I can use this in the Case
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You don't need a `CASE`. If you use `DateDiff` with `dd`, it will return the number of days difference (with the appropriate +/- signs) automatically. Since you didn't show where you want the days difference to display, or what the column name was you wanted to diff from today's date, I can't offer actual SQL to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,GetDate(), MAX(AmountPay.DateUpto)) AS [ PaidUpTo], TimeTable.Name, TimeTable.Ref, TimeTable.Time11to12 FROM AmountPay FULL OUTER JOIN TimeTable ON AmountPay.Ref = TimeTable.Ref WHERE (TimeTable.Time11to12 = @Time11to12) GROUP BY TimeTable.Name, TimeTable.Ref, TimeTable.Time11to12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

```
DateTime oldDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4);
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan span = oldDate.Subtract(today);
string diff = span.Days.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MySQL, your select statement should be like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), MAX(AmountPay.DateUpto)) AS [ PaidUpTo], 
    TimeTable.Name, 
......
```

DATEDIFF will give you values like -1, 1, -5 ...and your DataGridView should display those values just fine.